# Reading non standard tags in a RSS feed

Tags: c#, rss, syndication-item

I'm trying to write an RSS feed for the Ferrari site, but I can't read it all, using SyndicationItem. The problem is that the method getContent() reads only `<link>`,`<title>` and `<description>` elements (all of them are children of `<item>`). I need to read also the content of the `<textnews>` element, child of `<item>`. I must modify this query:

```
feed.LoadFromXml(feedXML);
// Query LINQ per effettuare il mapping
return feed.Items.ToList().Select(x =>
    new FeedItem
    {

        Title = x.Title.ExtractText(),
        Uri = x.GetUri(),
        Id = (x.ItemUri != null) ? x.ItemUri.ToString() : x.Title.ExtractText(),
        PubDate = x.PublishedDate.ToLocalTime().DateTime,
        Content = x.GetContent(),
        PlainTextContent = x.GetContent().ToPlainText(),
        Subtitle = string.Empty,
        ContentType = x.GetContentType(),
    }).ToList();
```

Can you help me?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to parse the document as an XDocument, then parse each node. Eg:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(aString);
var news = doc.Element("textnews").InnerText;
```

Comment: I am experiencing problems in doing this, the feedXml object used is of XmlDocument type,and every query XPath I try  raises an exception.